# phpMyAdmin and Drupal sites don't render after 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS upgrade

Tags: apache2, mysql, phpmyadmin

I updated from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS yesterday. All seemed well until I tried to browse to `localhost/phpmyadmin/` or any of my local Drupal sites. My Drupal sites don't render any content at all (no error, nothing in error.log) and `localhost/phpmyadmin` renders the text I'll paste below.

I'm seeking trouble-shooting advice.

```
addJSON( 'list', PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('recent')->getHtmlList() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if (isset($_REQUEST['git_revision']) && $GLOBALS['is_ajax_request'] == true) { PMA_printGitRevision(); exit; } echo '
'; } // Handles some variables that may have been sent by the calling script $GLOBALS['db'] = ''; $GLOBALS['table'] = ''; $show_query = '1'; // Any message to display? if (! empty($message)) { echo PMA_Util::getMessage($message); unset($message); } $common_url_query = PMA_URL_getCommon(); $mysql_cur_user_and_host = ''; // when $server > 0, a server has been chosen so we can display // all MySQL-related information if ($server > 0) { include 'libraries/server_common.inc.php'; include 'libraries/StorageEngine.class.php'; // Use the verbose name of the server instead of the hostname // if a value is set $server_info = ''; if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= htmlspecialchars($cfg['Server']['verbose']); if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ' ('; } } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || empty($cfg['Server']['verbose'])) { $server_info .= $GLOBALS['dbi']->getHostInfo(); } if (! empty($cfg['Server']['verbose']) && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { $server_info .= ')'; } $mysql_cur_user_and_host = $GLOBALS['dbi']->fetchValue('SELECT USER();'); // should we add the port info here? $short_server_info = (!empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose']) ? $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['verbose'] : $GLOBALS['cfg']['Server']['host']); } echo '
' . "\n"; // Anchor for favorite tables synchronization. echo PMA_RecentFavoriteTable::getInstance('favorite')->getHtmlSyncFavoriteTables(); echo '
'; if ($server > 0 || count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 ) { if ($cfg['DBG']['demo']) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('phpMyAdmin Demo Server') . '
'; echo '

'; printf( __( 'You are using the demo server. You can do anything here, but ' . 'please do not change root, debian-sys-maint and pma users. ' . 'More information is available at %s.' ), 'demo.phpmyadmin.net' ); echo '
'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
' . __('General settings') . '
'; echo '

    '; /** * Displays the MySQL servers choice form */ if ($cfg['ServerDefault'] == 0 || (! $cfg['NavigationDisplayServers'] && (count($cfg['Servers']) > 1 || ($server == 0 && count($cfg['Servers']) == 1))) ) { echo '
    '; include_once 'libraries/select_server.lib.php'; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_host.png') . " " . PMA_selectServer(true, true); echo '
    '; } /** * Displays the mysql server related links */ if ($server > 0 && ! PMA_DRIZZLE) { include_once 'libraries/check_user_privileges.lib.php'; // Logout for advanced authentication if ($cfg['Server']['auth_type'] != 'config') { if ($cfg['ShowChgPassword']) { $conditional_class = 'ajax'; PMA_printListItem( PMA_Util::getImage('s_passwd.png') . " " . __('Change password'), 'li_change_password', 'user_password.php' . $common_url_query, null, null, 'change_password_anchor', "no_bullets", $conditional_class ); } } // end if echo '
    '; echo '
    ' . "\n" . PMA_URL_getHiddenInputs(null, null, 4, 'collation_connection') . ' ' . "\n" . ' ' . PMA_Util::getImage('s_asci.png') . " " . __('Server connection collation') . "\n" // put the doc link in the form so that it appears on the same line . PMA_Util::showMySQLDocu('Charset-connection') . ': ' . "\n" . ' ' . "\n" . PMA_generateCharsetDropdownBox( PMA_CSDROPDOWN_COLLATION, 'collation_connection', 'select_collation_connection', $collation_connection, true, true ) . '
    ' . "\n" . '
    ' . "\n"; } // end of if ($server > 0 && !PMA_DRIZZLE) echo '

'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Appearance settings') . '
'; echo '

    '; // Displays language selection combo if (empty($cfg['Lang']) && count($GLOBALS['available_languages']) > 1) { echo '
    '; include_once 'libraries/display_select_lang.lib.php'; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_lang.png') . " " . PMA_getLanguageSelectorHtml(); echo '
    '; } // ThemeManager if available if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ThemeManager']) { echo '
    '; echo PMA_Util::getImage('s_theme.png') . " " . $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']->getHtmlSelectBox(); echo '
    '; } echo '
    '; echo PMA_Config::getFontsizeForm(); echo '
    '; echo '

'; // User preferences if ($server > 0) { echo '

    '; PMA_printListItem( PMA_Util::getImage('b_tblops.png') . " " . __('More settings'), 'li_user_preferences', 'prefs_manage.php' . $common_url_query, null, null, null, "no_bullets" ); echo '

'; } echo '
'; echo '
'; echo '
'; if ($server > 0 && $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Database server') . '
'; echo '

    ' . "\n"; PMA_printListItem( __('Server:') . ' ' . $server_info, 'li_server_info' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Server type:') . ' ' . PMA_Util::getServerType(), 'li_server_type' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Server version:') . ' ' . PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . ' - ' . PMA_MYSQL_VERSION_COMMENT, 'li_server_version' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Protocol version:') . ' ' . $GLOBALS['dbi']->getProtoInfo(), 'li_mysql_proto' ); PMA_printListItem( __('User:') . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($mysql_cur_user_and_host), 'li_user_info' ); echo '
    '; echo ' ' . __('Server charset:') . ' ' . ' '; if (! PMA_DRIZZLE) { echo ' ' . $mysql_charsets_descriptions[$mysql_charset_map['utf-8']]; } echo ' (' . $mysql_charset_map['utf-8'] . ')' . ' ' . '
    ' . ' 

' . '
'; } if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo'] || $GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowPhpInfo']) { echo '
'; echo '
' . __('Web server') . '
'; echo '

    '; if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['ShowServerInfo']) { PMA_printListItem($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'li_web_server_software'); if ($server > 0) { $client_version_str = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getClientInfo(); if (preg_match('#\d+\.\d+\.\d+#', $client_version_str)) { $client_version_str = 'libmysql - ' . $client_version_str; } PMA_printListItem( __('Database client version:') . ' ' . $client_version_str, 'li_mysql_client_version' ); $php_ext_string = __('PHP extension:') . ' '; if (PMA_DatabaseInterface::checkDbExtension('mysqli')) { $extension = 'mysqli'; } else { $extension = 'mysql'; } $php_ext_string .= $extension . ' ' . PMA_Util::showPHPDocu('book.' . $extension . '.php'); PMA_printListItem( $php_ext_string, 'li_used_php_extension' ); $php_version_string = __('PHP version:') . ' ' . phpversion(); PMA_printListItem( $php_version_string, 'li_used_php_version' ); } } if ($cfg['ShowPhpInfo']) { PMA_printListItem( __('Show PHP information'), 'li_phpinfo', 'phpinfo.php' . $common_url_query, null, '_blank' ); } echo ' 

'; echo '
'; } echo '
'; echo '
phpMyAdmin
'; echo '

    '; $class = null; // We rely on CSP to allow access to http://www.phpmyadmin.net, but IE lacks // support here and does not allow request to http once using https. if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['VersionCheck'] && (! $GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->get('is_https') || PMA_USR_BROWSER_AGENT != 'IE') ) { $class = 'jsversioncheck'; } PMA_printListItem( __('Version information:') . ' ' . PMA_VERSION . '', 'li_pma_version', null, null, null, null, $class ); PMA_printListItem( __('Documentation'), 'li_pma_docs', PMA_Util::getDocuLink('index'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Wiki'), 'li_pma_wiki', PMA_linkURL('http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/'), null, '_blank' ); // does not work if no target specified, don't know why PMA_printListItem( __('Official Homepage'), 'li_pma_homepage', PMA_linkURL('http://www.phpMyAdmin.net/'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Contribute'), 'li_pma_contribute', PMA_linkURL('https://www.phpmyadmin.net/contribute/'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('Get support'), 'li_pma_support', PMA_linkURL('https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/'), null, '_blank' ); PMA_printListItem( __('List of changes'), 'li_pma_changes', 'changelog.php' . PMA_URL_getCommon(), null, '_blank' ); echo ' 

'; echo '
'; echo '
'; echo '
'; /** * Warning if using the default MySQL privileged account */ if ($server != 0 && $cfg['Server']['user'] == 'root' && $cfg['Server']['password'] == '' ) { trigger_error( __( 'You are connected as \'root\' with no password, which' . ' corresponds to the default MySQL privileged account.' . ' Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to' . ' intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by' . ' setting a password for user \'root\'.' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * As we try to handle charsets by ourself, mbstring overloads just * break it, see bug 1063821. */ if (@extension_loaded('mbstring') && @ini_get('mbstring.func_overload') > 1) { trigger_error( __( 'You have enabled mbstring.func_overload in your PHP ' . 'configuration. This option is incompatible with phpMyAdmin ' . 'and might cause some data to be corrupted!' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * mbstring is used for handling multibytes inside parser, so it is good * to tell user something might be broken without it, see bug #1063149. */ if (! @extension_loaded('mbstring')) { trigger_error( __( 'The mbstring PHP extension was not found and you seem to be using' . ' a multibyte charset. Without the mbstring extension phpMyAdmin' . ' is unable to split strings correctly and it may result in' . ' unexpected results.' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } if ($cfg['LoginCookieValidityDisableWarning'] == false) { /** * Check whether session.gc_maxlifetime limits session validity. */ $gc_time = (int)@ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime'); if ($gc_time < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity'] ) { trigger_error( __( 'Your PHP parameter [a@http://php.net/manual/en/session.' . 'configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime@_blank]session.' . 'gc_maxlifetime[/a] is lower than cookie validity configured ' . 'in phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login might expire sooner ' . 'than configured in phpMyAdmin.' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } } /** * Check whether LoginCookieValidity is limited by LoginCookieStore. */ if ($GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] != 0 && $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieStore'] < $GLOBALS['cfg']['LoginCookieValidity'] ) { trigger_error( __( 'Login cookie store is lower than cookie validity configured in ' . 'phpMyAdmin, because of this, your login will expire sooner than ' . 'configured in phpMyAdmin.' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check if user does not have defined blowfish secret and it is being used. */ if (! empty($_SESSION['encryption_key']) && empty($GLOBALS['cfg']['blowfish_secret']) ) { trigger_error( __( 'The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Check for existence of config directory which should not exist in * production environment. */ if (file_exists('config')) { trigger_error( __( 'Directory [code]config[/code], which is used by the setup script, ' . 'still exists in your phpMyAdmin directory. It is strongly ' . 'recommended to remove it once phpMyAdmin has been configured. ' . 'Otherwise the security of your server may be compromised by ' . 'unauthorized people downloading your configuration.' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } if ($server > 0) { $cfgRelation = PMA_getRelationsParam(); if (! $cfgRelation['allworks'] && $cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] == false ) { $msg_text = __( 'The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely ' . 'configured, some extended features have been deactivated. ' . '%sFind out why%s. ' ); if ($cfg['ZeroConf'] == true) { $msg_text .= '
      ' . __( 'Or alternately go to \'Operations\' tab of any database ' . 'to set it up there.' ); } $msg = PMA_Message::notice($msg_text); $msg->addParam( '', false ); $msg->addParam('', false); /* Show error if user has configured something, notice elsewhere */ if (!empty($cfg['Servers'][$server]['pmadb'])) { $msg->isError(true); } $msg->display(); } // end if } /** * Warning about different MySQL library and server version * (a difference on the third digit does not count). * If someday there is a constant that we can check about mysqlnd, * we can use it instead of strpos(). * If no default server is set, $GLOBALS['dbi'] is not defined yet. * Drizzle can speak MySQL protocol, so don't warn about version mismatch for * Drizzle servers. * We also do not warn if MariaDB is detected, as it has its own version * numbering. */ if (isset($GLOBALS['dbi']) && !PMA_DRIZZLE && $cfg['ServerLibraryDifference_DisableWarning'] == false ) { /** @var PMA_String $pmaString */ $pmaString = $GLOBALS['PMA_String']; $_client_info = $GLOBALS['dbi']->getClientInfo(); if ($server > 0 && /*overload*/mb_strpos($_client_info, 'mysqlnd') === false && /*overload*/mb_strpos(PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION, 'MariaDB') === false && substr(PMA_MYSQL_CLIENT_API, 0, 3) != substr( PMA_MYSQL_INT_VERSION, 0, 3 ) ) { trigger_error( PMA_sanitize( sprintf( __( 'Your PHP MySQL library version %s differs from your ' . 'MySQL server version %s. This may cause unpredictable ' . 'behavior.' ), $_client_info, substr( PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION, 0, strpos(PMA_MYSQL_STR_VERSION . '-', '-') ) ) ), E_USER_NOTICE ); } unset($_client_info); } /** * Warning about Suhosin only if its simulation mode is not enabled */ if ($cfg['SuhosinDisableWarning'] == false && @ini_get('suhosin.request.max_value_length') && @ini_get('suhosin.simulation') == '0' ) { trigger_error( sprintf( __( 'Server running with Suhosin. Please refer to %sdocumentation%s ' . 'for possible issues.' ), '[doc@faq1-38]', '[/doc]' ), E_USER_WARNING ); } /** * Warning about incomplete translations. * * The data file is created while creating release by ./scripts/remove-incomplete-mo */ if (file_exists('libraries/language_stats.inc.php')) { include 'libraries/language_stats.inc.php'; /* * This message is intentionally not translated, because we're * handling incomplete translations here and focus on english * speaking users. */ if (isset($GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang]) && $GLOBALS['language_stats'][$lang] < $cfg['TranslationWarningThreshold'] ) { trigger_error( 'You are using an incomplete translation, please help to make it ' . 'better by [a@https://www.phpmyadmin.net/translate/' . '@_blank]contributing[/a].', E_USER_NOTICE ); } } /** * prints list item for main page * * @param string $name displayed text * @param string $listId id, used for css styles * @param string $url make item as link with $url as target * @param string $mysql_help_page display a link to MySQL's manual * @param string $target special target for $url * @param string $a_id id for the anchor, * used for jQuery to hook in functions * @param string $class class for the li element * @param string $a_class class for the anchor element * * @return void */ function PMA_printListItem($name, $listId = null, $url = null, $mysql_help_page = null, $target = null, $a_id = null, $class = null, $a_class = null ) { echo PMA\Template::get('list/item') ->render( array( 'content' => $name, 'id' => $listId, 'class' => $class, 'url' => array( 'href' => $url, 'target' => $target, 'id' => $a_id, 'class' => $a_class, ), 'mysql_help_page' => $mysql_help_page, ) ); }
```

Comment: I solved it. I essentially needed to back-grade from php 7 to php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I essentially needed to back-grade from php 7 to php 5.6